# Ansible: Find string in array and return string from array

Tags: ansible

I am writing up a playbook that takes a user input to find out if the file exists in the directory.

This is what I have so far

```yaml
- name: Encrypt file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    working_directory: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    enc_files: []
    my_file: shared_config

  tasks:

    - name: Get all Decrypted .yaml files
      find:
        paths: "{{ working_directory }}"
        patterns: '*.yaml'
        recurse: yes
        excludes: "*.enc.yaml,decrypt.yaml,encrypt_all.yaml,encrypt_file.yaml"
      register: files

    - name: Add Decrypted files to Array
      set_fact:
        enc_files: "{{ enc_files + [item.path | basename] }}"
      loop: "{{ files.files }}"
      no_log: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ enc_files }}"
      when: '"{{ my_file | lower }}" in "{{ enc_files | lower }}"'
```

What I can't seem to get to work is that it it finds if the file by name, not extension exists. If it does, I want to return the file with extension to do things with it.

Here is my current tree:

```
├── README.md
├── database
│   └── postgres_config.enc.yaml
├── decrypt.yaml
├── encrypt_all.yaml
├── encrypt_file.yaml
├── infra
│   ├── infra_config.enc.yaml
│   └── infra_config.yaml
├── middleware
│   ├── middleware_config.enc.yaml
│   └── middleware_config.yaml
├── services
│   ├── log_service_config.enc.yaml
│   ├── log_service_config.yaml
│
├── shared
│   ├── shared_config.enc.yaml
│   └── shared_config.yaml
```

What I want to do is have the user input either `shared_config` or `shared_config.yaml` and return `shared_config.yaml` so I can encrypt that file. I am also trying to figure out a way they can pass `shared config` in their input (as well as any of the other possible inputs, but I can try to figure that out on my own later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I wouldn't approach it this way (e.g. list all files and then find if the user input matches a files).

I would probably rather approach it the other way around: get the input of the user and then [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) that the corresponding file does exists.

Then you are just left with playing with Jinja filter and Python string manipulation to transform the user input in the expected path.

---

Below is a proposed playbook, with upside and pitfalls.

Upside:

- It will work with multiple chunk of path separated by spaces `some path` will give `some/some_path.yaml`
- It should be robust enough to correct erroneous multiple spaces: `some    path`  will give `some/some_path.yaml`
- It also accepts underscores `some_path` will give `some/some_path.yaml`
- It should be robust enough to correct erroneous multiple underscore: `some___path` will give `some/some_path.yaml`
- As well as a mix of both underscore and spaces `some path_here    multispace___multiunderscore` will give `some/some_path_here_multispace_multiunderscore.yaml`
- It works with or without extension specified in the user input
- It should give a bit of resilience against a transversal path attack

Pitfall:

- But it won't cope with a space between the last word and the extension, as it will bring an underscore too much: `some path .yaml` will give `some/some_path_.yaml`

---

And, so, here is the said playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: file_name
      prompt: Which decrypted file do you need?
      private: no

  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fqn: "{{ chunk.0 ~ '/' ~ chunk | join('_') if chunk | length > 1 else chunk | join('_') }}"
      vars:
        chunk: "{{ ((file if file.endswith('.yaml') else file ~ '.yaml')  | replace('_',' ')).split() }}"
        file: "{{ file_name | trim }}"

    - assert:
        that:
          - fqn is file  
          - not fqn.startswith('.') # I am just trying to limit transversal path attack here
          - not fqn.startswith('/') # I am just trying to limit transversal path attack here
          - "'enc' != fqn.split('.')[-2]" # this one is a protection against accessing the encrypted files
        msg: "{{ fqn }} is not a file"          

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Now, do whatever you like best with the file `{{ fqn | basename }}` at `{{ fqn }}` because I am sure it exists"
```

Here is two examples of running it:

- With a correct user input:

  ```
  Which decrypted file do you need?: middleware config

  PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
    msg: All assertions passed

  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => 
    msg: Now, do whatever you like best with the file `middleware_config.yaml` at `middleware/middleware_config.yaml` because I am sure it exists

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- With an erroneous user input:

  ```
  Which decrypted file do you need?: middleware config

  PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
    assertion: fqn is file
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: fake/fake_config.yaml is not a file

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

Comment: This helps signficantly, I really appreciate the help here. I have some research to do on some of the things you did here. 

How can I update it to return the file name though instead of dir/filename.yaml

Also is there a way we can make it match any file type except for .enc.extension?

Example:

match .txt
match .yaml

do not match enc.txt
do not match .enc.yaml

Comment: The `path/path_to_file` is reconstructed there: `fqn`. If you don't like/want it, you could just go: `fqn: "{{ chunk | join('_') }}"`

Comment: For the extension, build that in the assertions list e.g. `- "'.enc.' not in fqn"` or `- "fqn.split('.')[-2] != 'enc'"`

Comment: Also a neat trick to go back to a `file` with a `/path/to/file` in Ansible is the [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) filter. e.g. `{{ 'middleware/middleware_config.yaml` | basename }}` would give you `middleware_config.yaml`

Comment: ^--- all this is now in the edited version

Comment: Right I forgot about basename, I think i will just use that when I encrypt it with SOPS, I dont think updating the chunk is too important

Thanks this gives me a lot to review and study up on. I really appreciate the help and this is exactly what I was looking for!

In regards to building it into the assertions i am confused. The assertions already check if it is a file, what I meant was I want to check if shared_config.txt exists, if so do the thing with it.

Comment: Ahh i just realized, it is matching by dir/file name. Some files are inside dir not matching file names 

Like

services/client_service_config.yaml

Ill play with it and see if I can figure it out

Comment: Actually... I can work with this, really what I needed was the pre task formatting, from there I can use find and just remove the else file and leave it blank 

chunk: "{{ ((file if file.endswith('.yaml') else file ~ '')  | replace('_',' ')).split() }}"

From there I can use find to locate the file with the new formatted string if applicable and then located it by pattern without regex, this still works really well.